# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error with IIS 7and PHP 5.3

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I have configuired PHP 5.3 on IIS 7 using the following instructions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php and it works fine. Util I enable any extension from .ini file.

After enabling any php extension I am see the following errors :

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
•

IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
•IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
•IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
•The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
•The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

•Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
•Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
•Verify the permissions for the DLL.
•Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests,

Comment: •Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry .I know it is embrassing but I forgot to uncomment the extension directory

Comment: please mark it as answered. since I cant mark my own question to be answer untill it is 2 days old.